# Accessing and modifying variables using token concatenation in C

Tags: c, tokenize, stringification

I've been reading about stringification and token pasting and I was trying to access a variable using token pasting and modifying it's value. Is such a thing possible?

Suppose variables `a0` and `a1` are defined and at runtime I want to print their values using token pasting as `printf("\n\rValue is %d",VAR_PARSER(0));`
This is what I did.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

#define VAR_PARSER(dummyvar,index,value) do{\
dummyvar = index;\
a##dummyvar = value;\
}while(0);

unsigned char a0, a1, dummy;
int main (void)
{   
    unsigned char ucloopcnt;
    for(ucloopcnt = 0; ucloopcnt < 2; ucloopcnt++) VAR_PARSER(dummy,ucloopcnt,(ucloopcnt * 10));

    printf("\n\rValue is %d %d",a0,a1);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, at this line `a##dummyvar = value;` I wanted an output as `a0 = 10;` and `a1 = 20;` respectively. But it seems that it translates to `adummy`and gives the following error `adummy undeclared (first used in this funciton)`

Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve it as I'm curious to solve this.

Comment: Macros are for text-substitution; they will not evaluate variable values for you.

Comment: So, is there no way by which I can dynamically access variable names in a loop because I was trying to achieve that in the final step?

Comment: No; macros are a compile-time operation; you're trying to evaluate things with runtime values.

Answer (score 2):

Your expectation that `a##dummyvar` would evaluate to `a<value of dummyvar>` fundamentally misunderstands what macros do (i.e. simple text substitution). The output of `adummy` is correct.

You cannot achieve dynamic access of variable values at runtime through macros, like you're trying to here, since they are evaluated before compilation and have no knowledge of a program's state at runtime.

Comment: Okay. So, is there any other topic/ method I should refer if I want to achieve dynamic access of variables?